# HTML5 File API simple check if file exists

Tags: javascript, html, fileapi

I have a temporary File API store (HTML5) but I can't check whether a file exists or not. Is there a simple way to check it? Do I have to actually try and read the file to find out?

A search around has yielded me nothing concrete

A synchronous check would be nice is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to read the file. The following example is based on [this demo from HTML5Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-file-readingbyname) (it catches all errors, you might want to filter the [different error types](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/#errors-and-exceptions)):

```
    var errorHandler = function() {
        // File is not readable or does not exist!
    };
    fs.root.getFile('log.txt', {}, function(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(function(file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function() {
                // The file exists and is readable
            };
            reader.readAsText(file);
        }, errorHandler);
    }, errorHandler);
```

The synchronous method is only available to Web Workers, due to their blocking nature. The error handling is [slightly different](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem-sync/#toc-errors).

Comment: on the errorHandler i recive only the error... but i want download the file if doesn't exist