# Check if a HTML has loaded into a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to be able to set up HTML pages and load them into a single home page. Each html file will be named as the date (eg 03052016.html for today) and then the correct html will be pulled in each day on the homepage. 
However not all days will have a html file, in which case it should roll back to a previous day. I have successfully loaded the page, nice and easy but can't work out a way to identify that the page hasn't loaded and subtract one from the day. My current attempt is the following:

```
<body>
<div id="success"></div>
  <script>
      //section creates the html file name for today
        var today = new Date();
        var dd = today.getDate();
        var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

        if(dd<10) {
            dd='0'+dd
        } 

        if(mm<10) {
            mm='0'+mm
        } 
        today = dd+mm+yyyy+'.html';
        var today = "05052016.html";
      //do loop to subtract days until file is found
        do{
          var found = true; //variable records file presence
          $( "#success" ).load( today, function( response, status, xhr ) {
              if ( status == "error" ) {
                  var found = false;

                  if(parseInt(dd)>1){
                      dd = parseInt(dd)-1;
                  }else {
                      mm = parseInt(mm)-1;
                      dd = 30 //will deal with 31/30/28 day months later.
                  }

                if(dd<10) {
                    dd='0'+dd
                } 

                if(mm<10) {
                    mm='0'+mm
                } 
                today = dd+mm+yyyy+'.html';
                  //
                console.log( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
              }
            });
        }until(found == false )
    </script>
```

I am new to web authoring so please be brutal if I am way off how to implement this. It seems so easy but the loop just won't work!
I am currently testing in FireFox, and using jquery-1.10.2.js

Comment: If you can use HTML5 you can simply check if a file exists and load it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471866/html5-file-api-simple-check-if-file-exists

Comment: You need to understand that ajax (which is behind load) is asynchronous so you cannot test the found outside the success.

Answer (score 0):

check de length of the content of the quuestioned div.

```
        var div = $('div');
        var dHtml = div.html();
        var long = dHtml.length;

       if(long > 0)
       {
          //do stuff
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that ajax (which is behind load) is asynchronous so you cannot test the found outside the success.

Try this:

```
function pad(num) {return String("0"+num).slice(-2)}
function getFilename(date)
  var dd = pad(date.getDate());
  var mm = pad(date.getMonth()+1); //January is 0!
  var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
  return ""+dd+mm+yyyy+".html";
}
var date = new Date(), 
    aDay = 10*24*60*60*1000, 
  giveUp = new Date(date.getTime()-(10*aDay)); // max 10 days back
function loadFile(date) {
  $("#success").load( getFilename(date), function() {
    if (status == "error") {
      if (date>giveUp) {
        date.setDate(date.getDate()-1)
        loadFile(date);
      }
    }
  });    
}
$(function() {
  loadFile(date);
});
```